# Scraping nested element on ecommerce page (product swatch colors) using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the product swatch color names ('alt') and img srcs from Ulta's website when the swatch element is nested and has no class name. The result of my scraping includes other elements I don't want but I'm unsure (also very new to python and scraping) how to remove them.

Url: https://www.ulta.com/born-this-way-undetectable-medium-full-coverage-foundation?productId=xlsImpprod12621017

Screenshot of html:

[image: Screenshot]

My code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)

shade_names = []

elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('Loader__small')
for elem in elems:
    img = elem.find_element_by_tag_name('img')
    name = img.get_attribute('alt').encode('utf-8')
    shade_names.append(name)

print(shade_names)
```

Results of my code (I don't want the text before 'Cloud (fairest w/ rosy undertones)  ' and the quotation marks at the tail end):

'Ulta Beauty Collection', 'Chanel', 'Anastasia Beverly Hills', 'Clinique', 'Urban Decay Cosmetics', 'Bumble and Bumble', 'Tom Ford', 'Tarte Cosmetics', 'Makeup Revolution', "Kiehl's", 'Morphe', 'Too Faced', 'Fan fave', 'Too Faced Born This Way Undetectable Medium-to-Full Coverage Foundation Natural Beige (light medium w/ neutral undertones) #0', 'Too Faced Born This Way Undetectable Medium-to-Full Coverage Foundation Natural Beige (light medium w/ neutral undertones) #1', 'Too Faced Born This Way Undetectable Medium-to-Full Coverage Foundation Natural Beige (light medium w/ neutral undertones) #2', 'Too Faced Born This Way Undetectable Medium-to-Full Coverage Foundation Natural Beige (light medium w/ neutral undertones) #3', 'Too Faced Born This Way Undetectable Medium-to-Full Coverage Foundation Natural Beige (light medium w/ neutral undertones) #4', 'Too Faced Born This Way Undetectable Medium-to-Full Coverage Foundation Natural Beige (light medium w/ neutral undertones) #5', 'Shade Finder Image', 'Natural Beige (light medium w/ neutral undertones)  selected', 'Cloud (fairest w/ rosy undertones)  ', 'Swan (fairest w/ neutral undertones)  ', 'Snow (fairest w/ rosy undertones)  ', 'Ivory (fairest w/ golden undertones)  ', 'Pearl (very fair w/ rosy undertones)  ', 'Almond (very fair w/ golden undertones)  ', 'Seashell (very fair w/ rosy undertones)  ', 'Porcelain (very fair w/ neutral undertones)  ', 'Vanilla (fair w/ neutral undertones)  ', 'Nude (very light w/ rosy undertones)  ', 'Warm Nude (very light w/ neutral undertones)  ', 'Light Beige (light w/ neutral undertones)  ', 'Natural Beige (light medium w/ neutral undertones)  selected', 'Golden Beige (light w/ golden undertones)  ', 'Warm Beige (medium w/ neutral undertones)  ', 'Sand (medium w/ golden undertones)  ', 'Golden (medium w/ rosy undertones)  ', 'Praline (medium tan w/ golden undertones)  ', 'Warm Sand (tan w/ golden undertones)  ', 'Honey (tan w/ neutral undertones)  ', 'Caramel (rich tan w/ neutral undertones)  ', 'Brulee (rich tan w/ golden undertones)  ', 'Mocha (rich tan w/ rosy undertones)  ', 'Butter Pecan (richest tan w/ golden undertones)  ', 'Maple (deep w/ neutral undertones)  ', 'Chestnut (deep w/ golden undertones)  ', 'Chai (deep w/ golden undertones)  ', 'Mahogany (very deep w/ golden undertones)  ', 'Spiced Rum (very deep w/ rosy undertones)  ', 'Hazelnut (deepest w/ rosy undertones)  ', 'Cocoa (deepest w/ neutral undertones)  ', 'Tiramisu (deepest w/ golden undertones)  ', 'Sable (rich w/ rosy undertones)  ', 'Truffle (rich w/ golden undertones)  ', 'Ganache (richest w/ neutral undertones)  ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''

Comment: Check my answer, please. It's working. I am printing only the colors (without their parenthesis) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `time.sleep(10)` line I added the following part of code. To me it is working. Please, try it for you too.

**CODE**

```
time.sleep(10)

shade_names = []

elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ProductSwatches__Cell')
for elem in elems:
    img = elem.find_element_by_tag_name('img')
    name = img.get_attribute('alt')
    name = name.split(' ')[0]
    shade_names.append(name)

print([x for x in shade_names if x])
```

For me the result is this:

> ['Cloud', 'Swan', 'Snow', 'Ivory', 'Pearl', 'Almond', 'Seashell',
>   'Porcelain', 'Vanilla', 'Nude', 'Warm', 'Light', 'Natural', 'Golden',
>   'Warm', 'Sand', 'Golden', 'Praline', 'Warm', 'Honey', 'Caramel',
>   'Brulee', 'Mocha', 'Butter', 'Maple', 'Chestnut', 'Chai', 'Mahogany',
>   'Spiced', 'Hazelnut', 'Cocoa', 'Tiramisu', 'Sable', 'Truffle',
>   'Ganache']

I saw that there are 36 colors so the counter result is also correct.

Comment: Yes, it worked! I should've grabbed the parent (is that the right term?) class element. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes. You should check for unique class names so that your results are not going to have the same element with others (like list, menu, etc.). Thanks :)